# Is transaction required to close statement connection?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Having a Spring  DAO method

```
public List<T> findByQuery(String query, Object[] values, int indexStart, int page) throws DefaultException{                    
    try{
        final Query query_ = this.em.createQuery(query).setFirstResult(indexStart);         
        ....
        return query_.getResultList();                                                         
    }catch(Exception e){    
        throw new DefaultException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }                       
}
```

removing the Transactional annotation, keep the connection Opened after the statement closed

So my question is : is the transaction required for a simple Select Query ?

in this [exemple](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/221392?_sscc=t) a transaction is created for a simple select query

Comment: A "transaction" doesn't have to close anything. An EntityManager does (when it is closed). A query doesn't have to have a transaction around it

Comment: thank you indeed, EMF was not closed